# Session ID - Containing Data or Reference to Data?

Tags: security, web-applications, cookies, asp.net-web-api, sessionid

I would like your insight on "Session ID" for Web Application.

Which one of the following do you think is the best:

1. Session ID containing the following:
   `{ data: { user_id: ???, auth_user_agent: ???, auth_ip, ???, expires: unix_time }, signature: { "data's signature" } }` encrypted then base64ed => sent to the user
2. Random session ID referencing data in a Cache
3. Random session ID referencing data in a Database

I'm looking at performance and security here.

The bottom line is which one is better, (decrypting and verifying signature), retrieving from a cache or perform a db connection, retrieve data, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a random value to obtain the data from a fast non-relational cache like memcached is **much** faster,  and consumes less resources than transmitting this information in every single HTTP request the browser makes.  The browser will end up sending this session state to files that are unnecessary,  like static connects such as CSS, images.  This approach to session management will add unnecessary overhead to every client request to your server.

It is less secure,  because even though its encrypted,  nothing is perfect.  Unless you are an expert cryptographer,  avoid using encryption **at all costs**.